# Duda con carga de datos en ComboBox

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, combobox

**Buenas, tengo una duda con la carga de datos desde `SQL Server` en un `ComboBox`. Tengo una clase donde manejo todas las consultas a `SQl` donde tengo este método con la consulta:

```
    public List<Provincias> provincias()
    {
        List<Provincias> salida = new List<Provincias>();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(BD))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT id, provincia " +
                "FROM provincias";
            using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        int id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"]?.ToString());
                        string provincia = dr["provincia"]?.ToString();
                        Provincias p = new Provincias(id, provincia);
                        salida.Add(p);
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                    return salida;
                }
            }                
        }
    }
```

Esta es la clase **Provincia**:

```
class Provincias
{
    private int id { get; set; }
    private string provincia { get; set; }

    public Provincias(int id, string provincia)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.provincia = provincia;
    }
}
```

Y lo aplico así:

```
    private void menu1item1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        llenarProvincias();
    }

    private void llenarProvincias()
    {
        ConexionSQL conexionSQL = new ConexionSQL();
        cmbProvincias.ValueMember = "id";
        cmbProvincias.DisplayMember = "provincia";
        cmbProvincias.DataSource = conexionSQL.provincias();
    }
```

Pero esto me imprime lo siguiente:

```
ProvidusApp.Clase.Provincias
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: estoy seguro de que esta pregunta tiene un duplicado, pero echa un ojo a `DisplayMember` y `ValueMember'

Comment: Vale, era porque mis variables estaban en `private` @Pikoh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que indicar las propiedades `ValueMember` y `DisplayMember`

```
private void llenarProvincias()
{
    ConexionSQL conexionSQL = new ConexionSQL();

    cmbProvincias.ValueMember = "id";
    cmbProvincias.DisplayMember = "provincia";
    cmbProvincias.DataSource = conexionSQL.provincias();
}
```

Pero las propiedades debes definirlas `public`

```
class Provincias
{
    public int id { get; set;}
    public string provincia { get; set;}

    public Provincias(int id, string provincia)
    {
        this,id = id;
        this.provincia = provincia;
    }
}
```

No veo que al iterar el `reader` estas asignando un `id`

Comment: Tenías razón, era porque las variables estaban en privada. Muchas gracias :)